# NestJS serving JSON and adds a "default" section repeating the JSON

Tags: nestjs

I have a strange behaviour on an endpoint in NestJS serving a piece of JSON.
The JS with the JSON object is exporting

```js
module.exports = Object.freeze({
    translation: {
        TestMessage: 'Bienvenue à React et react-i18next'
    }
});
```

The result on the Client is:

```
{
    "translation": {
        "TestMessage": "Bienvenue à React et react-i18next"
    },
    "default": {
        "translation": {
            "TestMessage": "Bienvenue à React et react-i18next"
        }
    }
}
```

The question is where is the "default" coming from?

To paint the whole picture, below the module, controller and service:

#### Module

```js
import { Module } from '@nestjs/common';

import { LoggerService } from '@modules/logger';
import { I18nController } from './i18n.controller';
import { I18nService } from './i18n.service';

@Module({
    controllers: [I18nController],
    providers: [I18nService, LoggerService],
    exports: [I18nService]
})
export class I18nModule {}
```

#### Controller

```js
import { Controller, Get, Param } from '@nestjs/common';

import { LoggerService } from '@modules/logger';
import { I18nService } from './i18n.service';

@Controller('i18n')
export class I18nController {
    constructor(private logger: LoggerService, private i18nService: I18nService) {
        this.logger.setContext(I18nController.name);
    }

    @Get('/:lang')
    async getLanguage(@Param('lang') lang: string) {
        console.log(lang);
        return await this.i18nService.findOneByLanguageCode(lang);
    }
}
```

#### Service

```js
import { Injectable } from '@nestjs/common';

import { access } from 'fs/promises';
import { constants as fsconstants } from 'fs';

@Injectable()
export class I18nService {
    async findOneByLanguageCode(language: string): Promise<any | null> {
        const languagefile = __dirname + '/../../public/languages/' + language + '.js';
        await access(languagefile, fsconstants.R_OK);
        return await import(languagefile);
    }
}
```

From the Client I do a simple http://localhost:3001/i18n/fr-FR
and get the above result.

Again, where is the 'default' section coming from?

Comment: Do you happen to have `allowSyntheticDefaultImports` in your `tsconfig`? This looks like the `import` is reading a `default` export, hence the `default` in the JSON.

Comment: Yes!!, that's it. @JayMcDoniel, you are a hero. Thanks very much. In the documentation on allowSyntheticDefaultImports ( https://www.typescriptlang.org/tsconfig#allowSyntheticDefaultImports )  : "For convenience, transpilers like Babel will automatically create a default if one isn’t created."

Answer (score 0):

There should be `esModuleInterop` enabled in your `tsconfig.json`

https://www.typescriptlang.org/tsconfig#esModuleInterop

> a default import like import moment from "moment" acts the same as const moment = require("moment").default

That's why you have `default` object exist.

**tsconfig.json**

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
     "esModuleInterop": true, // change it to false or remove it
  }
}
```

Comment: I already had esModuleInterop set to True.  the solution is allowSyntheticDefaultImports which makes the extra default section. 
Thanks for your effort to answer my question .

Comment: What i mean is set `"esModuleInterop": false`, In my case, `"esModuleInterop": false` solve the problem but not setting `allowSyntheticDefaultImports`. 
But you find the `allowSyntheticDefaultImports: false` helps you, so thanks you @JayMcDoniel helps and cheers!